# CameraX face filters in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, snapchat

Is anybody know how to implement cameraX beauty effects like what google showed in there event. Like face mask, ar face filters etc. I am unable to find any documentation on Google. Just like snapchat face filters.
Or any other library which I can use for video recording and for face filters both.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: You got any solution for this?